# RichTextBlockOverflow and WinRT

Tags: windows, printing, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

How can I print a XAML page with pagination? I follow this sample: http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2013/01/20/Printing-from-MVVM-XAML-Windows-8-Store-apps.aspx. Here's my code:

```
<Page x:Class="U2UConsult.Win8.PrintingSample.MainPrintPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:local="using:U2UConsult.Win8.PrintingSample"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      mc:Ignorable="d">
    <RichTextBlock >
        <Paragraph>
            <InlineUIContainer>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedQuote}"
                               FontSize="32"
                               Foreground="Black"
                               Margin="16" 
                               TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            </InlineUIContainer>
        </Paragraph>
    </RichTextBlock>

</Page>
```

The problem is I only get one page from my text. Anyone can help me do the paging? Thanks. I still need the InlineUIContainer since I must do paging for the grid.